# types of maps that could be included in an android mapping app

Tags: android, mapping, maps, osmdroid, mapserver

what are the types of maps that can be supported by (or requested from server) I had heard about bitmaps, raster maps, and vector maps also maps tiles, I know that google maps and osmdroid (osm android mapping api) use maps tiles and when I download a map from osm mapnik using mobile atlas greater the tiles were downloaded as .png files (images) 
I want to know what other types of maps that can be supplied by a server (and displayed using osmdroid)because I want to develop android mapping app that work offline and let the user to include the map he/she wants???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up things here:

There are only two ways to represent map data.

- via an image of the map
- via vector data (GPS coordinates that when combined to lines etc result in the map)

All the map types you named (except for the vector map) are different names for images to represent the map. "Bitmap" is even a regular image (thats how .bmp files got their name) and has actually nothing to do with maps. Since the complete image of a map is really really big (some terrabytes?) you cut the image into tiles and transfer just those. That's a map tile then.

Using vector data is not practical (esp. for mobile devices) since you have to render the map image yourself. Since that takes longer than downloading an image you have google / osm and probably every other map service use images instead of vector data.

Comment: Thanks very much zapl, ok but when the map is represented as image then does this image contains geographic information(like GPS coordinates) so I can read my location and display it in the map

Comment: the map images don't contain locations directly but the location of e.g. the 4 corners of that image can be calculated somehow (or is transmitted by the server) and you can draw it then. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames seems to be how it works with OSM

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Google_Maps_Coordinates is a bit about how google does their coordinate <> image mapping.

Comment: thanks again zapl you are realy helpfull, I check the articles, and I understand that when maps are represented as images then this images contains information about GPS coordinates that is represented in the X,Y coordinates by some relation.
and that means if I want to dispaly an overlay (or my location) or go to aspecific Geopoint (by its GPS coordinates) them I can
is that right???